# Using <html><u> tags to make button text underlined, caused button to take up entire JToolBar

Tags: java, html, jbutton, underline

I need to have a button whose text is underlined and the only way I could find to do this in Java was to use  and  tags, but when I do this, it causes the button to take up as much room as is left in the JToolBar even though the text is short and it should only take up a small amount of space.  Here is how I create the Button.

```
      String buttonText = new String("<html><u>Lesson Plans</u></html>");
      JButton lessonButton = new JButton(buttonText);
      toolBar.add(lessonButton);
```

If I remove the  tags then it takes up the right amount of space but if I have them in there is takes up the entire toolBar.  Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to fix the problem by using:

```
button.setMaximumSize( button.getPreferredSize() );
```

Otherwise you should be able to just change the font to use an underlined font. Darryl's [Visual Font Designer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/visual-font-designer/) shows how to add attributes to a font.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the [paintComponent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method of your JButton, and write on it with any style and font.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing "" and wrote "" instead... This may be the reason for your problems.